# How to use loader.load("filename.json.gz") - Loading compressed file in threejs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, amazon-s3, three.js

I have already compressed and having **gz file** in **s3**. which is here, https://oic-accounts.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3d-try-json-files/gzip/3.json.gz

But when I try to load in threejs using `loader.load("https://oic-accounts.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/3d-try-json-files/gzip/3.json.gz", onLoadModel, this.xhrPercentage);`

Its not working and throwing `VM4245:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0` this error.

**P.S :** Uploaded gzip file `content type` is `application/json`

Thanks for your valuable read and answers :)

Comment: When opening the URL I see an `Access Denied` error message. You should check at your AWS backend if the permissions are defined correctly.

Comment: Think some auth made. i am not sure. But I got a solution from slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question bit awkward. but if someone face this issue in future, it will be helpful for sure.

So, Straightaway. Set `content-encoding:'gzip', content-type:'application/json` in aws header for the file and remove **.gz** from url. That's it :)